# Can't replace NA's with Date

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I cannot replace the NA's for some reason even if I use the is.na code. I want to replace the NA with the current date. Any ideas?

Here is what my dataframe looks like:

```
df 

      Name     Parent        Date
1     A        no parent     OLD
2     B        no parent     NA
3     C        no parent     OLD
4     D        no parent     OLD
5     E        no parent     OLD
```

When I try this code it doesn't work:

```
today <- Sys.Date()
df[["Date"]][is.na(df[["Date"]])] <- today

str(df)
'data.frame':   2505 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Name  : chr  " A" " B"  "C" "D" ...
 $ Parent: chr  "no parent" "no parent" "no parent" "no parent" ...
 $ Date  : chr  "OLD" NA "OLD" "OLD" ...
```

Comment: Are we talking `df[is.na(df$Date), "Date"] <- as.character(today)`? Please note you can't pass it as a Date class to a character column. Otherwise it will be converted to it's integer representation and then to a character

Comment: It worked thanks! Can you make it an answers so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Date in R is just a `double` with a `Date` class attribute. Once the attribute stripped off - it just becomes a `double`. see

```
attributes(today)
# $class
# [1] "Date"

unclass(today)
# [1] 16897

storage.mode(today) ## data.table::as.IDate uses an integer storage mode
# [1] "double"
```

And a single column can't hold several classes in R. From `[<-.data.frame`

> When [ is used with a logical matrix, each value is coerced to the
>   type of the column into which it is to be placed.

Investigating the `[<-.data.frame` documentation I"m not sure how the conversion to a `character`, happens, probably

```
as.character(`attributes<-`(today, NULL))
# [1] "16897"
```

Or

```
as.character(unclass(today))
# [1] "16897"
```

While you are looking for

```
as.character(today)
## [1] "2016-04-06"
```

---

So to sum it up, this should do

```
df[is.na(df$Date), "Date"] <- as.character(today)
```